# How to add new data into Future<dynamic> in dart / flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a chat system in mobile application using `Flutter` / `Dart`.

I have fetched a user's message records from server by API and received result as `Future<dynamic>`. This result has list of chat data. If I pass it to `FutureBuilder` widget. It works and lists chat records in `listTile`. Everything is working well.

When user adds a new chat message then I post the that text message to server by API to store into database. It works and response status is 200 which means message has been added on server's database.

I have instance of newly added chat message, I want to append / add it to previously fetched `Future<dynamic>` result.

Kindly suggest me how can I do this? Can we update `Future<dynamic>` typed data? Thanks.

Comment: What is your database or backend. (eg firebase)

Comment: I am using Lumen 8 for backend services and Flutter/dart for mobile application.

Answer (score 1):

`Future` can emit only one item by design. If you want to emit multiple items, use `Stream`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html

To get to know how to generate streams have a look on this: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams

Most likely what you want to do is use `rxdart`'s `BehaviorSubject` or dart's `StreamController` (they share api, so just substitute the name, except for `ValueStream`, which is specific to rxdart, this one will have to be replaced with just `Stream`):

```dart
class Api {
  final _subject = BehaviorSubject<DataToDisplay>();
  ValueStream<DataToDisplay> get data => _subject.stream;


  void fetchData() {
    final data = downloadDataFromSomewhere();
    _subject.add(data);
  }
}
```

Then just create a `StreamBuilder` similarly to `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It means A Future can't listen to a variable change. It's a one-time response. Instead, we'll need to use a Stream. Ok, I will go with Streambuilder instead of Futurebuilder. Thanks mightybruno.

Comment: FutureBuilder is used for one time response, like taking an image from Camera, getting data once from native platform (like fetching device battery), getting file reference, making an http request etc. On the other hand, StreamBuilder is used for fetching some data more than once, like listening for location update, playing a music, stopwatch, etc.